# Call to groovy service from pl/sql procedure

Tags: oracle, grails, stored-procedures, groovy, plsql

Is it possible to make a call to a groovy service from an Oracle pl/sql stored procedure? I know normally it's the other way around, but I've heard this is possible yet unable to find much documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl.php. It contains the step-by-step instructions for setting up access to web services.

I have been successfully using this to retrieve data from a web service for over two years.